# using Autohotkey on windows 10 allows window key to open start menu

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, hotkeys

I've got some AutoHotKey scripts that I use to move windows around my monitors.  for example, I have `[Shift]`+`[Win]`+`[Up]` set to move the current window to the monitor above the current one ans size proportionally

My problem is that, since upgrading to windows 10 on Friday, executing one of these functions still performs its hotkey action, but then when I release the Shift key while still holding Window, the start menu opens.  When I was still on 7, the start menu would only open if I pressed and released the Window key without pressing any other keys.

I don't have this problem with my hotkeys that use Control+Window instead of Shift. It's only when I press and release the Shift key while holding Window.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try adding #MenuMaskKey, #UseHook (and maybe KeyWait) as in [this example](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MenuMaskKey.htm#Examples).

Comment: I added `#MenuMaskKey vkFF` and `#UseHook` to the top of my script but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your hotkey sends any keys other than LWin/RWin, that should suppress the Start menu. For example, `Send {Blind}{vkFF}`.

If it fails to suppress the Start menu, that most likely means the Win key is being released (virtually or physically) before you send the key, or released and pressed again after you send the key, and is not being masked correctly. You can troubleshoot this by using `KeyHistory`, which should show a Win-down immediately followed by a Win-up, and should indicate whether these events were generated by AutoHotkey and with what timing.

The Start menu should appear only if you press and release a Win key while not holding any other modifier keys, and without pressing or releasing any other keys. In other words, what you describe should not be possible unless your hotkey is directly or indirectly releasing Shift and pressing and/or releasing the Win key (and Send is failing to mask it).

Recent versions of AutoHotkey do not mask the Win key when used in hotkeys like `+#Up::`, because the presence of the Shift key has already masked it.